# Pass argument to a function in batch

Tags: function, batch-file

I am trying to create a simple batch script that has a procedure with single argument. Following some sources on internet I have created the following example code:

```
:logMessage
   @echo on
   echo Hi, %1
   @echo off
goto :eof

call:logMessage "Izomorphius"
```

But I am not getting the output I have expected - only "Hi," is printed, without the argument. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only problem with your code is that as it stands, the execution will never reach your `call` statement. To get it to work, add the line `goto main` at the very top, and add the line: `:main` just above your `call` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all batch functions need to be defined at the end of the file, after any of the calling code.

```
call:logMessage "Izomorphius"
goto :eof

:: Start function definitions ---

:logMessage
   @echo on
   echo Hi, %1
   @echo off
   goto :eof
```

Comment: *"I think all batch functions need to be defined at the end of the file"* - No. Batch is really old. Functions can be defined literally **anywhere** in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version that works

```
@echo off
call :logMessage "Izomorphius"
goto :eof

:logMessage
echo Hi, %1
```

Note that it actually prints the quotes around `Izomorphius`, but just remove them if you don't want them.

Comment: You might need the quotes if you want to pass more than one word in the %1 parameter e.g. "Izomorphius Smith".  In that case, to remove the quotes you could then use `echo Hi, %~1`

Answer (score 1):

You code only needs to be tweaked:

```
goto main                                     & :: Add this line...
:logMessage
   @echo on
   echo Hi, %1
   @echo off
goto :eof

:main                                         & :: ...and this line.
call:logMessage "Izomorphius"
```

as per my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code is buggy, but this is another trick:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo.
set "NAME=Izomorphius"
call :prepend NAME Hi
echo Message: %NAME%
echo.
goto :end

:: Functions
:prepend @varname @value
set %1=%2 !%1!
exit /B 0
:end
pause
```